# Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.when i am creating vw

Tags: sql, view

```
SELECT 
    `bqm`.`project`.`project_id` AS `project_id`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`project_name` AS `project_name`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`project_manager` AS `project_manager`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`updated_by` AS `updated_by`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`created_dt` AS `created_dt`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`updated_dt` AS `updated_dt`,
    `bqm`.`project`.`archive` AS `archive_status`,
   ( SELECT 
           `u`.`user_name` AS NAME
        FROM
            (`bqm`.`project` `p`
            right JOIN `bqm`.`user` `u` ON (`p`.`created_by`=`u`.`user_id`))) as Name
FROM
    `bqm`.`project`;
```

Comment: Since you have correlated subquery in your `SELECT` statement, you must be sure that the subquery is return only one value. Add `LIMIT 1`

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Why don't you join the `user` table directly to your main query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what DBMS you're using as the syntax doean't appear to validate, but i'd move the join outside the select clause like so;

```
SELECT 
    Prj.project_id AS project_id,
    Prj.project_name AS project_name,
    Prj.project_manager AS project_manager,
    Prj.updated_by AS updated_by,
    Prj.created_dt AS created_dt,
    Prj.updated_dt AS updated_dt,
    Prj.archive AS archive_status,
    Usr.User_name as Name
FROM  bqm.project as Prj
Join  bqm.user    as Usr   on Usr.user_id = Prj.created_By;
```

The issue you're getting is because the sub-query in the select clause isn't linked to the "main" query, meaning for every row in the Project table you'll have every row in the sub-query. By moving the join to the main query as I've suggested above will eliminate this.